# Atmega328 not sending data to screen

Tags: atmega328p

hello I have an atmega328p with code on it to display graphics on a screen. It works when I upload it to an Arduino uno but when I upload it to an atmega328p that is powered by the Arduino it does not display the graphics on the screen. I checked the pins on the screen using a multimeter and this is what I got:
When the red prong is at vcc:

```
  gnd:3.25v
  ce: 0.54
  reset: 0.52
  DC:  0.56
  D/In: 0.22
  clk: 0.22
```

When the red prong is at ground:

```
 gnd .29v
 ce: .27v
 rst:.28v
 dc: .29v
 d/in: .29v
 clk:.27v
```

Everything is wired up correctly can someone please tell me whats wrong. I am using the u8glib library to run my nokia 5110 screen. Here's a schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: edit your question.  Right now, it is impossible to tell what voltages you are measuring/reading.  Perhaps use the equals (=) sign to show your results.  Also,  the standard way to measure voltage is with the negative (black) lead of voltmeter connected to ground. Red lead (+) to the point you want to measure.

Comment: done the edit...

Comment: Looks like the reset (rst) line is low.  Until reset line is hi (3.3v), the display won't turn on

Comment: does it matter if it is in an analog output instead of digital

Comment: The reset pin needs to be pulled HI.  Whether you accomplish this by using a digital output from 328P,  or, you could connect the display reset pin to 3.3v using a resistor (220 ohms or higher).

Comment: the reset pi n now reads 3.3v but the rest of them are still 0.5v and the display isn't working

Comment: Without seeing your schematic, I can help no farther.  Hopefully you have added a crystal to your 328P.  Your UNO has a 16Mhz crystal on the circuit board.  Draw a schematic of your circuits, add to your question to obtain more help.

Comment: @marla I have added the schematic

Comment: That is not a schematic, nor does it make any sense. There are many free schematic capture software packages; please do not torture us with this.

Comment: Did you program the fuses on the new ATmega328P?

Answer (score 1):

Since comments have gotten so many, I am making an answer, even though this answer isn't definitive.

First :  I don't see the reset line for your ATmega328P being pulled high (to 3.3v) Vcc.

Second :  Step back from your project for a moment. Download a "Blink" program and run that, to assure that your 328P is capable of operating properly.

If Blink program (or equivelant) works, then I will recommend migrating this question to the Arduino SE.

Also,  you need to add decoupling capacitor from Vcc to ground right at the 328P chip.  A value of 100nf (nano-farad).

You don't show the frequency of your crystal.  Your program is likely written for 16Mhz (since you started with an UNO)

Comment: Neither the lack of a reset pullup, nor in most of these cases the lack of a bypass capacitor (though those are a good idea) is likely to be the impeding issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for helping. I wasn't sure whether 328P had internal pullup for reset.